meanings of modal verbs in context

"He must work tomorrow"

I think that I coulf reported this sentece in two ways. Either " She said he must or had to work the other day"? Correct?
Am I right that this sentence has two meanings? One is "order". Let's say I'm an angry boss saying to my employee "You must work tomoorw or I'll fire you. Then we change "must to had to". The other meaning is assumption. Let's say I'm a mother and I saw my son's timetable then I could say "You must work tomorrow because I saw you timetable. Then we leave "must" unchanged

Please fix  your spelling.

Without surrounding context to disambiguate - Yes, He must work tomorrow is ambiguous. It could mean 1) I'm quite certain that he will work tomorrow (with any number of nuances of difference depending on exact context). OR ir could mean 2) He is obliged to work tomorrow (again, potentially with a range of context-specific nuances). But this is really a quirk of the fact that you're just looking at a few words in isolation. In the real world it's staggeringly unlikely that any native Anglophone could ever misinterpret the utterance if delivered by another native Anglophone.

The mother would probably say "You must be working tomorrow..."

Must (Obligation) vs. Must (Speculation) in Reported Speech
OP has correctly stated the rule for "must" in reported speech (explanation below).
When changing direct speech to reported speech, we usually backshift the verb.
However, according to the Cambridge dictionary, the handling of "must" depends on its meaning:

Reported speech, Modal verbs.
.
1. Obligation (Order/ Command):.
For obligations, "must" often changes to  "had to" in reported speech, following conventional grammar rules.
.
Example:.

Direct: "You must pay by 30th April."
Reported: She said we had to pay by 30th April.
Rule: Must (obligation) usually becomes had to..
.
2. Speculation/Inference.
When  "must" expresses speculation or deduction, it remains unchanged in reported speech if the assumption is still valid.
.
Example:
Direct: "It must be awful to live in such a noisy place."
Reported: She said it must be awful to live in such a noisy place.
Rule: Must (speculation) does not change.


According to BBC Learning English, while it is possible to change "must" to "had to" for obligations, it is not always necessary:

must, ought to, used to, needn't

“We must leave right now.”
They insisted they must/had to leave straightaway.
"You must try not to worry.”
They told me I must try not to worry.


In summary, "must" backshifts to "had to" for obligations but remains unchanged for speculation.

He must work tomorrow. = future
The OP's example: She said he must or had to work the next day? Correct?
The correct form with MUST: She said he must have had to work the next day.
She said he had to work the next day. is correct but less strong.
tomorrow in the present become next in the past.

Or "She said he had to work the next day". ('Tomorrow' would be the day after she said it.)
